# Проблема с назначением роли юзеру

Tags: c#, asp, role

Я хочу скрыть некий функционал на сайте от незарегистрированных пользователей. Для этого у меня есть роли я их могу назначать, но я хочу чтобы когда человек заходит не зарегистрированный он не будет видеть доп функционал, а когда зарегается, то будет видеть и поэтому я вызываю метод  MakeNewUserLikeUserRole(user.Id, roles); в том месте где создаётся юзер, то есть по моей логике юзер создался и ему автоматически присваивается роль "user", а все юзеры могут видеть скрытый от не зарегистрированных людей функционал. Но не тут то было, почему-то вылетает ошибка.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        List<string> roles = new List<string>() { "user" };

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User user = new User { Email = model.Email, UserName = model.Email, Year = model.Year };
            // добавляем пользователя
            
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // установка куки
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
                
                MakeNewUserLikeUserRole(user.Id, roles);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MakeNewUserLikeUserRole(string userId, List<string> roles)
    {
        // получаем пользователя
        User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (user != null)
        {
            // получем список ролей пользователя
            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, roles);

            //return RedirectToAction("UserList");
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

Comment: `когда человек заходит не зарегистрированный он не будет видеть доп функционал` вам не нужны роли для этого. Если юзер не заркгистрирован, у него не может быть никакой роли.

Comment: Согласен, но я хочу чтобы пока не зареган - нет роли, когда зареган - появилась роль, не важно какая, а этот функционал могут видеть только те у кого есть хоть какая-то роль

Comment: а почему просто не проверить, если не зареган - то не показывать, заркган - показывать?

Comment: `Но не тут то было, почему-то вылетает ошибка.` текст ошибки? Строка с ошибкой?

Comment: Там на самом деле неошибка вылетает. а просто сайт открывается, как я понимаю метод асинхронный и сайт продолжает работать, а роль так и остаётся не присвоена

Comment: `MakeNewUserLikeUserRole(user.Id, roles);` => `await MakeNewUserLikeUserRole(user.Id, roles);` ?

Comment: Работает. Спасибо))

Comment: я бы ещё сделал метод `MakeNewUserLikeUserRole` приватным и снял `[HttpPost]` с него. Вы эе не планируете его из браузера вызывать?